# How can I subset a TIF file based on non-NAN values in a different TIF file?

Tags: matlab

I have two TIF files with the exact same dimensions covering the geography of US.

TF1 has mostly NAN values with a small area of non-NAN values

TF2 has non-NAN values all across US.

I want to

1. Find which cells in TF1 has non-NAN values (x = isnan(TF1))
2. Find the values in TF2 for exactly those cell locations
3. Create a matrix TF3 which has the same dimension as TF1/TF2, and contains the values of TF2 for non-NAN locations of TF1

How can I accomplish this?

I found this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/174603-replace-nan-with-corresponding-elements-in-another-array

But wasn't able to apply to my use case

Comment: What do you have until now ? Where are you stuck ? Can you include some sample code ?

Comment: Are your .tif files colour? ie. are you variables `TF1` and `TF2` size `HxW`, or `HxWx3`?

Comment: How can I get this information in Matlab? Could you please give me the command? But yeah, when I do imagesc(TF1) or Imagesc(TF2), I get color images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code you need:

```
indecesValid = ~isnan(TF1);

TF2(indecesValid) = TF1(indecesValid);
```

You can simply set the values you want to set in your TF1 matrix with those from the TF2 matrix.

To obtain the values of TF2 which are in the locations which are non-NaN in TF1 simply

```
TF3 = TF2 .* indecesValid;
```

Code I used to generate some test cases:

```
TF1 = magic(5);
TF2 = nan(5);

TF2(1,1) = -1;
TF2(1,2) = -1;
TF2(1,4) = -1;
TF2(2,3) = -1;
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand this: indecesValid = ~isnan(TF2); I want to find the values in TF2 fr non-NAN values in TF1. Shouldn't yours be TF1 too? Or am I missing something...

Comment: Woops, I mixed up your TF1 and TF2 for some reason.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting some output. But I think it is not what I want. This is putting the values of TF1 into TF2. But I want to keep the values of TF2 for those cells where TF1 has non-NAN values....Hope I have been clear..

Comment: This is the difference between the mathworks link I provided in the question. I don't want to replace values, but simply subset the existing TF2.

Comment: Oh okay, I've reread your question and think I now understand what you want. Check my latest edit.